# How to merge two dataframes based on cell value within other dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

My first dataframe is something like this:

```
df1=pd.DataFrame({'ID':['514401202200037121','514401202200037334','514401202200037010','514401202200037210','514401202200036890'], 'ModEff':['0.207','0.205','0.211','0.204','0.206'], 'Rs':['0.297020','0.297250','0.296899','0.297111','0.297035'], 'Isc':['11.296','11.248','11.287','11.198','11.301']})
```

Second dataframe contains same ID numbers but they are random and not on same index.

```
df2=pd.DataFrame({'ID':['514401202200037334','514401202200037010', '514401202200037210','514401202200036890','514401202200037121'],'No':['50653','50653','50653','50653','50653']})
```

My goal is to get raw data (all columns) from first df to second one for matching ID numbers. However, I am not able to align them by ID.

Since I'm new to code, and none of the codes I've tried works, I'm posting without code sample.

*

Comment: please add the data as text to your question (see [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example))

Comment: Pasting pictures of the sample data is discouraged and should be replaced with the data in a text (copy-paste) format.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pandas Merging 101](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53645882/pandas-merging-101)

Comment: updated with data

Answer (score 0):

Please let me know if this works:

```
pd.merge(df1, df2, on='ID')
```

Answer (score 0):

`df2.merge(df1)`

This works as both dataframes have the same "key".